# How to git clone a project into red hat app studio using app studio?

Tags: kubernetes, redhat, redhat-containers, redhat-sso

I want to clone a project into my red had app studio workspace using my devfile. How to do this?

Need a sample devfile.yaml code

```
schemaVersion: 2.2.0
metadata:
  name: my-workspace
  version: 1.0.0
  displayName: My Workspace
  description: Workspace for My Project

starterProjects:
  - name: go-temp
    git:
      remotes:
        origin: "https://github.com/atiq-rahman-or/gotemp.git"
```

This code is used by me